# логический оператор OR в blade laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

использую laravel версии 5.8 и в шаблоне blade хочу использовать такую конструкцию `{{$student->name OR ""}}` судя по некоторым источникам должно работать, но мне выдает ошибку

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

, решат эту проблему `{{(isset($student->name)?$student->name: "")}}`, но всё же что нужно сделать чтобы заработал первый вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в 5.7 версии (но это не точно, не помню..) заменили `or` на `??`

```
{{$student->name ?? ""}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот из документации абзац:

> Если вы хотите использовать стиль «where» для ваших объединений, то
> можете использовать для этого методы where() и orWhere(). Вместо
> сравнения двух столбцов эти методы будут сравнивать столбец и значение

https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/queries